# Preference of grignard between aldehyde and double bond?

Tags: reaction-mechanism

Quick question, in this reaction:

2-Butenal + CH3MgBr  -->  ??

Will the grignard attack the double-bond or the aldehyde carbon?
Please explain this preference, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Grignard will first attack the aldehyde carbon, giving you a secondary alcohol. Since the alcohol is strongly polarized, it would be difficult for the double bond to be attacked.

Comment: Thanks! So just to clarify, the major product will be the secondary alcohol and that is what prevents a second addition.

Comment: This does however not explain why Grignard reagents react different than Gilman cuprates ;)

Comment: Actually, under the reaction conditions, the magnesium is an ion for the oxygen. This creates a strong negative characteristic to the molecule so the Grignard reagent cannot do a second attack. However, if the alcohol is purified and then reacted with more Grignard reagent, then addition at the double bond is likely. (I'm not familiar with Gilman cuprates.)

Comment: @ Klaus, I do remember my professor saying something about how Gilman reagants were "soft nucleophiles" and would preserve the carbonyl group. I don't think he explained why this happened though; it would definitely make for another good question.